# Change a divs z-index using jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I have some jquery that im running to create an animation for a custom menu.

Basically you click on the menu icon and it runs a CSS animation to fill up the screen. I am trying to only pull that menu #menuIcon's z-index to be above the red background that has animated in, but I am not sure how to go about doing that.

So the CSS in question is:

```
.phoneBig{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 0px;
    animation-name: example;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    transform-origin: 50% ;
    z-index: 200;
}
```

Making this less than #menuIcon. It is also important to note that #menuIcon currently does not have any styling, it is just being used for the click event in the jQuery, I tried making its z-index 201 but that didn't seem to work.

Here is a fiddle with the working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/vy6fLa03/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can call jquery to do this :

```
$(this).parent().css('position', 'relative');
$(this).parent().css('z-index', 3000);
```